# Creating an email using HTML and inserting a logo file (png)

Tags: html, moqui

This is a part of code (an html code) used to prepare the body of an email message:

```
<tr><td>
    <a href="http://www.something.com">
        <img src="${sri.buildUrl('/rsk.png').url}" alt="Logo">
    </a>
</td></tr>
```

I have the png file in the webroot/screen/webroot directory, but I just cannot get it to work. What is the proper way to get the resource location properly, so that the logo displays correctly?

Comment: Can you confirm that the value of the src attribute resolves to full path? i.e. `http://ww.mysite.com/file.png`

Comment: Yes, I use the file on the login page. **<img src="rsk.png" alt="Logo" class="center-block" style="box-shadow: 0px 2px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);">**. This is what html behind the login page says.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Image was not accessible, since I tested it on local only.